# Discussion: Encryption for Password Keeper Android application

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, mobile

The other day, Google notified me that my Gmail account may have been compromised as it had been accessed by two IP addresses from out-of-the-ordinary locations. Since I generally (and stupidly) use the same password for every website, I decided to change things up and use different passwords.

Being an Android developer, I have decided to start developing a password keeper application for which I can store my usernames and passwords, as it is difficult to remember different passwords. I do not want to take the easy route and download an existing third party password keeper application.

This got me thinking, what is the best way to secure usernames and passwords in my application? Currently, I require a password to view a list of accounts that can be added. I am also storing usernames and passwords into a database. It seems that Android cannot natively encrypt a database, however. I could encrypt the values that I store in the database, but if someone got their hands on my phone, they could find out the encryption if they really wanted to. Or, I could use a server for encryption/decryption, but then you have a server that has to be maintained and can be compromised.

I would love to get some opinions on the topic. While I know that perfection cannot be achieved, what would be a good method to implement for my Android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are certainly going to require the user to provide a PIN or password every time they want to add/view the password list, right? Why not use that as the encryption key, meaning that if someone gets your phone they still cant acces or decrypt the passwords without knowing the user defined key.

Comment: Yes, I am requiring that the user define a default PIN or password. I had not thought about using the PIN/password as the encryption key, however. I like that idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the application [1password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) they are probably the best password keeper app on the market.  Their philosophy is they store all your passwords behind a 128bit encrypthon where you use your 1password to get in.  Other than that all website passwords are randomly generated alphanumeric strings. So there is really no collision chance and you are safe where ever you browse.

You shouldn't use a server that just means that people can assume their passwords are sitting somewhere and if you are a good app developer the passwords on the server will be just as secure as if you store them client side.

As for finding out the encryption if they "really wanted to"  That is really up to the user picking the one password they key all their information with.  Yes, it is possible to crack encryptions with brute force but if the user picks a non dictionary alpha numeric string, the probability of getting through is near impossible.  Also if you encrypt everything properly, they cannot just "break" the encryption.

Last just because I can

[image: To anyone who understands information theory and security and is in an infuriating argument with someone who does not (possibly involving mixed case), I sincerely apologize.]

Credits [XKCD](http://xkcd.com)